# Implementing automatic Github API v3 calls in Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, github-api

I’m trying to upgrade an old Wordpress plugin that lists a user’s latest commits on their website. It was very straightforward with github API v2, but v3 is making it a whole lot more complex.

Feature-wise, it’s very simple: when the plugin is running, it lists the commits on the Wordpress site, and automatically refreshes its content every N minutes (configurable by the Wordpress admin). The administrator just needs to set it up once and it figures out when to re-query github to get the latest data.

But with github API v3 any request to get even public data requires the OAUTH token. After reading over their docs again and again, it appears that it can’t be automated to work the way I want.

First, I don’t want to store the user’s github password anywhere (because it would need to be encrypted two-way to be used in the API calls, which isn’t safe enough), so the basic authentication method is out. Which leaves the  “Web Application Flow” example here (http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/). But that involved redirecting the actual user to github to accept the request. This is no good either.

Am I misunderstanding anything, or is it simply not possible to re-create the plugin to work as it currently does?

Please let me know if I’m not clear on anything!

Answer (score 0):

> But with github API v3 any request to get even public data requires the OAUTH token.

This is simply not true. For public data - you can query GitHub's API endpoint without any credentials passed. See for example this API call to fetch user info: https://api.github.com/users/izuzak

So, to get all the events performed by a user, just call the API like so:
https://api.github.com/users/izuzak/events

Notice that this gives you **all** events, not just commit event (e.g. it gives you also watch events), so you have to filter them out. See this for all event types: http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/

Also, instead of invoking the API endpoint, there's always the option of:

- using the ATOM feed for a user (notice the little feed icon on a users activity page, e.g. https://github.com/izuzak?tab=activity):
  https://github.com/izuzak.atom
- or the equivalent JSON document: https://github.com/izuzak.json

Still, both of these give you all events for a user, not just commits.